# Taking out or crop image covered by Rect(top,left,right,bottom) just like cropping using Camera_intent

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an ImageView and over that ImageView i have drawn a Rect(top,left,right,bottom) which is movable with touch events .Now i want to crop the IMAGE which is the SOURCE of ImageView according to the area covered by rect.. It's like cropping...I am thinking of using..

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint);
```

but Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static Bitmap CropImage(Image source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            var bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Instead of just pasting the code, can you add an explanation.  It might make a lot of sense to you but others may have issues understanding.

Comment: this code only gives top left cropping but not bottom right cropping ...so  i also need a proper code.